# Problem with Date Formatter

Tags: iphone

i want to show date.

I am using code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMddHHmmss"];
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
```

But it shows 0921164432 PM.

i dont want to show PM how can i  do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `[dateFormat setPMSymbol:@""];`?

PS: As I can't reproduce the problem, I just can presume...